# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]I tried to use IsDecomposedBy and Decomposes code in Python Console in Blender bim but it shows this error:

```
>> project.IsDecomposedBy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'IsDecomposedBy'


>> project.Decomposes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Decomposes'
```

Comment: Please add the _entire_ traceback to your question, along with a cut'n'paste of the Python code that the problem is in.  But as far as I know, 'IsDecomposedBy' is not a valid attribute in Blender.

Comment: I had added an image of the code

Answer (score 0):

The variable `project` is a list containing one element. You can access the IfcProject with `project[0]`, which will have the attributes `IsDecomposedBy` and `Decomposes`.